# how to connect to mongo atlas from my node.js and express server with mongoose package

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, connection

**Title: MongoDB Atlas Connection Issue - ETIMEDOUT Error**

**Body:**

I am encountering an issue while trying to connect my Express server to MongoDB Atlas, and I'm seeking assistance as I've exhausted several solutions. Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const uri = process.env.MONGODB_URI;

const connectDB = mongoose.createConnection(uri, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
});

const UserSchema = require('../models/User');
const taskSchema = require('../models/Task');
const projectSchema = require('../models/Project');
const MessageSchema = require('../models/Message');

const User = connectDB.model('User', UserSchema);
const Task = connectDB.model('Task', taskSchema);
const Project = connectDB.model('Project', projectSchema);
const Message = connectDB.model('Message', MessageSchema);

module.exports = { connectDB, User, Task, Project, Message };
```

The error I'm facing is as follows:

```
const timeoutError = new error_1.MongoServerSelectionError(`Server selection timed out after ${serverSelectionTimeoutMS} ms`, this.description);
                                     ^

MongoServerSelectionError: connect ETIMEDOUT 13.37.173.41:27017
```

i don't know how to solve this i try all solutions chatgpt provide to me and also youtube solution if someone face the same problem please provide me a solution

Answer (score 0):

First of all keep you connection command in 'try-catch' block so that you can have proper error message. Check if your firewall is blocking something. Search solution for it. Today only I gone through this and sharing my connection code below if it can help:

```
try {
    const connect = await mongoose.connect(process.env.CONNECTION_STRING);
    console.log("Databse Connected With HOST: ",
        connect.connection.host       
    );
    console.log("Databse Connected With NAME: ",connect.connection.name);
} catch (error) {
    console.log("Connection Error: ", error);
    process.exit(1);
}
```